# Guice bind a class and its adapter

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

I would like implement a Guice module which binds an adapter to a named argument, but to create this adapter, it needs to instantiate another class, which also need injected arguments.

Here is the example in Scala:

```
trait Service

class UserService @Inject()(@Named(value = "foo") foo: String) extends Service

trait Adapter

class AdapterImpl(service: Service) extends Adapter

class AdapterRef(val adapter: Adapter)


class Module extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    val fooValue = "bar"

    bind(classOf[String])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("foo"))
      .toInstance(fooValue)


    val userService = new UserService(fooValue)     //It should be instantiated by Guice somehow

    bind(classOf[AdapterRef])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("userService"))
      .toInstance(new AdapterRef(new AdapterImpl(userService)))   //Thats kinda ok
  }
}
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thank you,

Gabor

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There is no error. I need a solution which can replace the line: " val userService = new UserService(fooValue)" because I would like the system to inject all the dependencies into that.

Comment: You create an injector and pass in the module. Then you get instances from the injector. Docs: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Guice.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings) method within your module, which lets you remove the binding. This is my best effort at Scala so if the syntax is incorrect let me know.

```
@Provides() @Singleton() def provideAdapterRef(service: Service): AdapterRef = {
    return new AdapterRef(new AdapterImpl(service))
}
```

Note the use of Singleton to imitate your examples use of `toInstance`. If you don't need it to always provide the same instance I would recommend removing the scope and letting it create a new one every time.

An alternative solution is to use a [Provider](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings). This requires you to keep a modified version of the binding in your module and create an extra class, but it can be a cleaner solution if your Provider is more complex.

```
//Can inject UserService as well, or provide annotations to configure which
//implementation of Service you get if you have more than one.
class UserServiceProvider @Inject()(service: Service) extends Provider[AdapterRef] {
    override def get(): AdapterRef {
        return new AdapterRef(new AdapterImpl(service))
    }
}
```

Then you can change your binding in the module to

```
bind(classOf[AdapterRef])
  .annotatedWith(Names.named("userService"))
  .toProvider(classOf[UserServiceProvider])
  .in(classOf[Singleton])
```

Here note the use of `in(Singleton)` to replicate your `toInstance` behavior.